# Simple mysql into text file: How to avoid the first line being written?

Tags: mysql

This is a simple .bat file which currently 'works'; I'm looking to avoid having the field name as the first line in the text file.

> C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u sample -pnotpass --database test -e "SELECT url FROM single WHERE fold = 'bb' AND dir= 'test_folder' ; " > test123.txt

Obviously, it's not a "Windows related question"; Is there a way to ask mysql to only print the results and skip the field name?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a "column-names" paramater which defaults to true. Just set it to false.

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u sample -pnotpass --database test --column-names=false -e "SELECT url FROM single WHERE fold = 'bb' AND dir= 'test_folder' ; " > test123.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the precise format you require, but I'm guessing that using [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) would probably be a step in the right direction. It would also remove the need to redirect the content to a file, although you'll need to remove that file once you've finished with it (or at the start of the batch file) otherwise MySQL will spit tacks the next time it tries to create it and discovers it already exists.

For example, to create a CSV style file you could use:

```
SELECT url INTO OUTFILE "\wherever\test123.txt" 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
FROM single WHERE fold = 'bb' AND dir= 'test_folder' ;
```

Incidentally, the user in question must have the FILE privilege for INTO OUTFILE to work.

Comment: Thanks middaparka, I'll test it now. BTW, are you saying 'SELECT INTO OUTFILE' will not over-write an existing file?